# Error in using cvVideoWriter in opencv?

Tags: c++, video, opencv, codec

This code snippet is supposed to save part of a video whose range is defined by `start` and `end`. There is an array of structures (`data[i]`) that holds the starting and end frame of a video shot in the original video.  There are total of 8 shots.

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalCount-1; ++i) {
    capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("Stats\\Shots\\Cricketc1.avi");
    assert(capture);

    int frame_number = 0;
    int start = data[i].start_frame;
    int end   = data[i].end_frame;

    char shotname[100];
    strcpy_s(shotname, "shot_");
    char shot_id[30];
    _itoa_s(data[i].shot_no, shot_id, 10);
    strcat_s(shotname, shot_id);
    strcat_s(shotname, ".avi");

    IplImage* image = NULL;

    CvVideoWriter* writer = NULL;
    writer = cvCreateVideoWriter (shotname, CV_FOURCC('i','Y','U','V'), fps, cvSize(width, height), 1);
    assert(writer);
    while (frame_number >= start && frame_number < end) {
        image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        assert(image);
        cvWriteFrame(writer, image);
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&image);
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cout << shotname << " saved ..." << endl;
}
```

After running the program 8 video files are created that have a size of 6kb and do not run. I have tried various codecs like divx, mjpg, mpg2, iyuv etc but all give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Gunther Fox answer won't help try to use different codec - it's very strange, but in my situation iyuv is not working at all and some other codecs works ok, but i can't read them while debugging... For me - ms video and radius cinepak always works fine(writing and reading), iyuv is not working at all, other codes - writing and reading, but not while debugging.

Comment: Radius cinepack is not working in my system. Is there a way by which I can find the codecs installed by opencv ????

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` loop, `frame_number` is never incremented.  Since you say the program actually executes and creates the files this means nothing in your `while` loop ever runs... otherwise you'd get stuck in an infinite loop because `frame_number` will always be `0`.

I would advise you initialize `frame_number` to `start` instead of `0` and there's no reason for it to exist outside of the scope of the loop so a `for` seems more appropriate:

```
int start = data[i].start_frame;
int end   = data[i].end_frame;

...

for (int frame_number = start; frame_number < end; frame_number++) {
    image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    assert(image);
    cvWriteFrame(writer, image);
}
```